# How to completely disable Oomph in Eclipse?

Tags: java, eclipse

For a long time it was annoying in Eclipse to switch workspaces and also to lose (not permanently of course) carefully crafted settings like colors, styles, etc. And it was again annoying to recreate these settings from scratch (thus creating a new workspace was as rare as possible). And I was extremely happy to see someone decided to do something about it, so we get Oomph. But longer I use it, more I think that the solution is actually worse than the original problem. First of all, it just doesn't work as one would expect. So I said to myself: "OK, give it a time, be patient, maybe you just don't know how to properly use it" (and probably I still can't). But after few years I end up with dozens of different versions of Eclipse installed around, because of this Oomph thing. And now (Oxygen.3a) it is tied to Eclipse and apparently I can't remove it.

But why would I do that? Because I'm loosing control over the settings! It changes syntax color at its whim, ignores indeterminably part of these settings (Java Editor Syntax Color) and other settings too. Oh, I tried to disable recording or startup task, but to no avail. Can't I just have these colors as picked? Actually I promise, I would not complain about setting these things from scratch in each workspace again, but please, let someone tell me, how to get rid of Oomph functionality. PLEASE.

I guess there should be separate settings for Eclipse "style" and these should shared among Eclipse versions and instances (like via `~/.config/eclipse/` or what) and "environment" settings that are strictly involved in building/running the code that are tight to workspaces. I believe it would be way simpler to maintain the stuff. But at this point I just would like to know, how to disable Oomph to return to the old, well known hell. Is that even possible?

Comment: The downloads on the [Eclipse Project page](http://download.eclipse.org/eclipse/downloads/) don't use Oomph at all

Comment: Are you 100% sure it doesn't contain Oomph plugin inside? As I downloaded (NOT via Oomph) official distro and Oomph is there already.

Comment: The Eclipse Project downloads are extremely minimal and definitely don't use Oomph. I always use these downloads.

Comment: I'll give it a try, thanks.

Comment: The Oomph GUI and documentation could certainly both be improved. That said, your post provides no evidence to back up your claims. As a start, go to directory _{Eclipse install directory}\eclipse\configuration\org.eclipse.oomph.setup_. In there you will find a file named **setup.log** which  clearly details every occasion where Oomph has been used for workspace configuration. Lines starting with _"Performing Preference..."_ will detail the specific changes. Post the portion of that log where you believe Oomph made configuration changes that you did not request.

Comment: @greg-449 Really! no oomph in https://download.eclipse.org/eclipse/downloads/

Comment: What happens if you remove from your main eclipse folder the org.eclipse.oomph.setup folder and from /plugins all the org.eclipse.oomph.* files?

Comment: @gordon That's an interesting idea — I'll give it a try when I'm done with my work.

Answer (score 1):

Everytime when I change pref in eclipse to ignore `unnecessaryElse`

```
org.eclipse.jdt.core.compiler.problem.unnecessaryElse = ignore
```

When I close eclipse, and restart it again. The above pref will be changed automatically to the following

```
org.eclipse.jdt.core.compiler.problem.unnecessaryElse = warning
```

Finally, I found that **oomph** alway `Executing startup tasks` to **restore or change** my pref settings. This is unacceptable.

At last, I add `-Doomph.setup.skip=true` to eclipse/eclipse.ini, and now oomph nolonger restore or change my pref settings.

```
-Doomph.setup.skip=true
```

Comment: This does not answer OPs question, please read [answer], thanks.